# Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods error | XCode 11.3 running on iOS 13.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode11.3

I got this error when compiling and run my current ios code using Xcode 11.3 on simulator ios 13.3.

> objc[32297]: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods.

[image]

However, the same code was compiled and simulated successfully using the same Xcode 11.3 on simulator ios 12.1 .

Does anybody have idea how to solve this issues?

Thank you. ^_^

Comment: I think the problem is Google Cast Framework, It needs to be updated.

Comment: @Ungapps already remove Google Cast Framework from the project file, but the same error still happening..